# Why ORA-03106 in an OCI program when SELECTing more than 1 row? 10g only, not 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-call-interface

My OCI application is returning ORA-03106 ("fatal two-task communication protocol error") when performing a `SELECT * FROM mytable` where `mytable` has four columns: `INTEGER`, `VARCHAR(1000)`, `FLOAT` and `DATE`, and two rows.  The call succeeds if there is only 1 row.  The call also succeeds if there is a `BLOB` column in the table (that is also being selected).

Various forums have indicated that `NLS_LANG`-related issues may be the cause - namely, that character set conversion is failing on the client when the data is retrieved, because (possibly) the character set conversion files cannot be found.  Note that I have tested many possible combinations of setting `NLS_LANG`, `NLS_CHARACTERSET`, `ORA_NLS10`, and other environment variables.  Setting certain of these impacts the observed behavior: sometimes, Oracle throws `ORA-01034: ORACLE not available ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist`; at other times the client application crashes before the first row is retrieved (the crash occurs inside `OCIStmtFetch2()`).  Notably, if the client application executes the following query when the connection is first established: `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,'`, the crash does not occur; instead, the `ORA-03106: fatal two-task communication protocol error` error is returned.

Note: it is possible that the presence of the `DATE` column is causing this - but establishing reproducible cases has proven to be very difficult, so I am posting my question as-is.

I have spent in excess of 50 hours attempting to resolve this problem.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**NEW: important additional details (see code snippet below)**: The problem ONLY occurs during PIECEWISE retrieval of data - it does not matter which of the two methods I use (a dynamic callback function, or the loop method using the get/set piece info functions).  Stepping through the debugger and looking at the buffers in memory that I have supplied to OCI to store the FETCHED data, all 4 fields in the first row are always retrieved properly; the initial FETCH of the second column (this is the call that returns with a request for info about the VARCHAR column when the looping approach is used) successfully populates all non-dynamic fields up to but not including the VARCHAR column (i.e., the INTEGER column is correctly populated); then the next FETCH successfully populates the VARCHAR field, and *should* successfully populate the remaining (non-dynamic) columns as well (the FLOAT and DATE fields); however, the FLOAT field is correctly populated, but the DATE field is corrupt, and furthermore, this FETCH call should return success, but instead it returns ORA-03106.

The following code snippet, stripped of irrelevant error-checking and other code, shows what is happening:

```
void RetrieveRow(...)
{
    // All necessary environment, statement, describe, and define functions
    // have already been called; non-dynamic buffers have already been allocated
    retcode = OCIStmtFetch2(mystmt, fConnection->myerrhp, 1, OCI_DEFAULT, 0, OCI_DEFAULT);
    while (retcode == OCI_NEED_DATA)
    {
        // ...
        // ... Define the necessary arguments to OCIStmtGetPieceInfo() here ...
        // ...
        OCIStmtGetPieceInfo(mystmt, fConnection->myerrhp, (dvoid**)&define, &type, &inout, &iter, &idx, &piecep)

        // ...
        // ... Iteratively allocate and increase the buffer size for the required dynamic column here...
        // ...
        OCIStmtSetPieceInfo(define, OCI_HTYPE_DEFINE, fConnection->myerrhp, buf, alenp, piecep, indp, rcodep)

        // ... Call OCIStmtFetch2() as part of the dynamic loop to fetch the next piece
        retcode = OCIStmtFetch2(mystmt, fConnection->myerrhp, 1, OCI_DEFAULT, 0, OCI_DEFAULT);
    }
    // retcode is OCI_SUCCESS here when RetrieveRow() is called for the first row,
    // ... and all data in the first row is properly populated in the buffers.
    // But, when RetrieveRow() is called the second time, the above loop is entered,
    // ... the INTEGER, VARCHAR (a dynamic field), and FLOAT fields are correctly populated,
    // ... but the DATE field is corrupt, retcode is OCI_ERROR, and the error is ORA-03106.
    // ... Note that even with a dynamic callback used instead of a loop, the error is the same.
    // ... Note that when piecewise (dynamic) fetching is NOT used,
    // ... all rows are retrieved successfully and there is no error.
}
```

Note: As reflected in my title change, this problem does NOT occur when OCI and Oracle 11g are used.  With the code COMPLETELY unchanged, but including the OCI 11g header files and loading the 11g OCI dll, running against an 11g Oracle database server listener/instance, the code succeeds WITHOUT this error.  It is only 10g in which the error occurs.

I would be satisfied if a reference can be provided that clearly and reputably identifies this as an OCI/Oracle *bug* in version 10g. (I am convinced that it is.)  However, I cannot find any confirmation that this is an OCI/Oracle bug.

Comment: Are you seeing anything in the alert log or listener log on the server, or the SQL*Net log on the client (if one is created)? Does it matter which of the two rows is available to be selected?

Comment: No errors whatsoever are reported in any of these logs.  I step through the code, and the FETCH function simply returns with error ORA-03106, as described above.

Comment: is your application multi-threaded?

Comment: All calls to OCI functions with the same OCI environment handle occur in a single thread.  Other threads may handle calls with a different OCI environment handle.  In my testing that reveals the above issue with 10g, there is only a single open environment handle and the corresponding single thread making OCI calls.

Answer (score 0):

What exact version of Oracle client and server are in use?

There's a possible match on at least one known Oracle bug:

> Applies to: Oracle Server - Enterprise Edition - Version: 10.2.0.1 to
> 10.2.0.2 - Release: 10.2 to 10.2 Information in this document applies to any platform.
> Checked for relevance on 21-Jan-2010
>
> Symptoms OCI
> based application intermittently throws ORA-03106: fatal two-task
> communication proto error and has error entries in application log.
>
> Important : The error may not bee seen in the alert.log and in the SQL
> NET trace files
>
> Cause This has been identified as a Bug 4523125
>
> Solution Upgrade the Client and the Server to 10.2.0.3

More generally, this seems like an issue for Oracle Support.

Comment: Thank you.  There are a variety of ORA errors for which Oracle provides no details, but for which they recommend upgrading.  In fact, we have tested against version 11g, and the problem is resolved.  This, and other tests, give strong evidence to me that I am correct that this is an OCI/Oracle bug.  However, I am looking for a bug report that is more specific (this one gives no specifics whatsoever, except that it's related to OCI).  Like so many Oracle issues, I think you'll find it's impossible to locate any information whatsoever about "Bug 4523125".

Comment: @Dan -- true, but if you can submit the issue to Oracle support they may be able to verify more specifically against their internal description of the bug.

Comment: Dave - We have not pursued Oracle Support, because we are only using the Express edition.  Also, we wanted to be as certain as possible that it was not our issue.  Finally, we anticipate a number of hours involved in the preliminaries when dealing with Oracle support, and we cannot afford that time.  Do you know if it is free to contact Oracle support, and is your experience with them positive?  (Unrelated note: StackOverflow strips the '@' sign from before your name at the start of this comment, and other comments.  I have no idea why.)

Comment: No, it sure isn't free, at least not in my experience.  I don't know what the support terms are for Express edition though.  I would say sometimes it's a positive experience and sometimes it's not, but often if the problem corresponds to a known bug they will identify it very quickly.

Comment: Oracle ought to make these bug lists easily available publicly.  But that is not their business model.  It impacts developers such as myself in the form of lost time and sleep.  A very good reason to strongly support open-source alternatives.